# Spark: Compare DataFrames from csv and parquet

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, parquet

I have a task to compare 2 DataFrames on equality.

The task seems to be trivial, but the problem is that one DF is created from csv, and other one- from parquet.

The csv-created DF has the following structure:

```
+-----------------+--------+--------------------+----------------+----------+-----+
|             John|     Doe|      120jeffersonst|       Riverside|        NJ|08075|
+-----------------+--------+--------------------+----------------+----------+-----+
|             Jack|McGinnis|           220hoboAv|           Phila|        PA|09119|
| "John""Da Man"""|  Repici|      120JeffersonSt|       Riverside|        NJ|08075|
|          Stephen|   Tyler|"7452Terrace ""At...|        SomeTown|        SD|91234|
|             null|Blankman|                null|        SomeTown|        SD|00298|
|"Joan ""thebone""|   Anne"|                 Jet|9th,atTerraceplc|DesertCity|   CO|
+-----------------+--------+--------------------+----------------+----------+-----+
```

And the parquet DF, created from column oriented format, has only 2 columns:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|        PAR1   ? ?  |                    |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|    6[1](Stephe...  |                    |
|    6 (Tyler...     |                    |
|    6[1](
________________________________________
|    ......          |                    |
```

Is there any way to compare this 2 DF, using DF.exceptAll methods?
Directly applying of this method entails to error, as expected, because of difference in columns number.

Comment: None of these two data frames look properly loaded from source. Obviously csv is without headers, delimiters are not properly configured, etc. On the other hand parquet format looks completely useless (at least part you posted).

Comment: If csv included headers and properly configured delimiters, is it allow to compare 2 DF, which include different number of columns? I doubt

Comment: Well if dataframes have different number or structure of columns they are not the same for sure. You must first make them have same structure. What are you actually comparing here?

Comment: Before to compare the content of the 2 dataframes, you should start by comparing the schema. Here, the schema is not the same, hence the 2 dataframes are different. If you only want to compare same columns you should select them before to compare.